# How can I align all children to the left in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, material-design

Here's my widget.

```
class IntroPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String image;
  final String title;
  final String subTitle;

  const IntroPage(this.image, this.title, this.subTitle, {super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        width: 280,
        height: 410,
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: Image.network(
                      image,
                      width: 220,
                      height: 220,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  child: Text(title,
                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 32.0),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  )
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.purple,
                  child: Text(subTitle,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                      ),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left),
                )
              ],
            )));
  }
}
```

And this is the state.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final List<Widget> pages = [
    const IntroPage(
        "https://hips.hearstapps.com/ghk.h-cdn.co/assets/16/08/1280x1919/gettyimages-179494696.jpg",
        "Title1",
        "subtitle"),
    const IntroPage(
        "https://www.hillspet.com/content/dam/cp-sites/hills/hills-pet/en_us/exported/dog-care/new-pet-parent/images/golden-retriever-puppy-running-outside.jpg",
        "Title1",
        "subtitle"),
    const IntroPage(
        "https://hips.hearstapps.com/ghk.h-cdn.co/assets/16/08/1280x1919/gettyimages-179494696.jpg",
        "Title1",
        "subtitle"),
  ];

  final PageController pageController = PageController();

  int currentPage = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    pageController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        currentPage = pageController.page!.round();
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: PageView.builder(
              itemCount: pages.length,
              controller: pageController,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => pages[index],
            ),
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: List.generate(pages.length, (index) {
              return Container(
                width: 8.0,
                height: 8.0,
                margin:
                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 2.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  color: currentPage == index
                      ? const Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.9)
                      : const Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.4),
                ),
              );
            }),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see. It sticks to the top and horizontally center.

What I am expecting is, all the children sticks to the left and center vertically.

So, All the children's left should be the same.

I thought `Container` always try to take the max width or max height. But It doesn't seem to be like that after I gave them background.

[image: preview]

Comment: On your column try adding `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start`

Answer (score 1):

[image]

- Treat the entire component as a single View and arrange them horizontally

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [..._youWidget()],
        ),
        Spacer()
      ],
    );
  }
```

- this is full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class IntroPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String image;
  final String title;
  final String subTitle;

  const IntroPage(this.image, this.title, this.subTitle, {super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.blue,
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [..._youWidget()],
          ),
          Spacer()
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> _youWidget() {
    return [
      Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        child: Image.network(image, width: 220, height: 220, fit: BoxFit.cover),
      ),
      Container(
          color: Colors.yellow,
          child: Text(
            title,
            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 32.0),
            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
          )),
      Container(
        color: Colors.purple,
        child: Text(subTitle,
            style: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 16.0,
            ),
            textAlign: TextAlign.left),
      )
    ];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I fixed it with doing try adding crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start on the Column.

Comment: ok, I just provide an idea to deal with more complex layouts